# If a state seceded from the United States, would its residents still owe US federal income tax under US law?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, secession

Assume Texas' threat to form a union of states materializes and those states break away and begin levying their own taxes. The USA continues to claim that territory but has no *de facto* control.

Are individuals in the rebellious states liable for federal taxes? If a state breaks away, can the IRS still try to collect taxes in that state, or is there some tax rule stating that things change?

If it was 1861 (or whatever), the Confederate citizens would have an enormous IRS bill in 1865, but that didn't happen because income tax didnt exist.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "opinion based". It is too speculative to have a definitive legal answer. In practice issues like this tend to be resolved on a case by case basis in a political matter in some sort of treaty or wartime decree, rather than having a primary resolution in a legal forum. U.S. Civil War precedents wouldn't necessarily be applied in a future dispute and past cases are of historical interest only.

Comment: I think you are mixing up successor with secesionist. The CSA were secesionists but not a successor state (the USA never recognized it, so from the USA POV they had always been part of the USA, even if in rebelion). If the CSA had succeeded, then there would have been two possibilities: it would become a new state (no obligations nor assets inherited from the USA) or it could have shared with the USA its former obligations and assets, becoming a successor state of the USA.

Comment: But would they pay taxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there some tax rule stating that things change?

There isn't.  US citizens are required to report their worldwide income to the IRS, and to figure their tax on the basis of their worldwide income, no matter where they live.

If the states' secession is recognized by the US government then there would be a negotiated agreement with terms governing all sorts of things that need to be taken care of in connection with that secession, not unlike the negotiations currently under way between the United Kingdom and the European Union.  (There would probably also have to be an amendment to the US constitution.)  In that case, the answer to this question would depend on the outcome of those negotiations.  Presumably the negotiations would include some mechanism for the residents of the states leaving the union to lose their US citizenship, along with changes to the Internal Revenue Code.

If the US does not recognize the secession then there won't be a secession.  The states would not be able to deploy sufficient military force to assert control over their territory.  The US citizens in those states would therefore remain US citizens, liable to the IRS.

Comment: Actually they would, almost all resources are in the purported confederacy

Comment: Ok, assume Texas secedes.  Does that mean that Texas suddenly has control over the US military bases located in Texas?  No.  The reality would be far more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, they will continue to owe taxes

... and fines and interest on those unpaid taxes.

In the wake of the Civil War, the legal issue as to if any part of the USA could break away without the consent of the Federal government was settled decisively: no.

Therefore, any such breakaway territory is still part of the USA, and any taxes owed remain owing until they are paid. You don’t discharge a debt by paying money to someone who is not the debtor.

Comment: Actually, I cant find records of Confederates paying IRS despite it existing in 1862

Comment: The first income tax in the United States was a 3% flat tax on anyone making $800 or more and became law in 1861 (this was the wealthy 3% of the population).   Income Tax was declared unconstitutional in 1895 by SCOTUS and the 16th Amendment to the Constitution reversed this decision.

Comment: So they didnt pay that then